# Account for a factor variability in a logistic GLMM in lme4

Tags: r, lme4

We did a field study in which we tried to understand which factors significantly explain the probability of a group of animals (5 species in total) crossing through 30 wildlife road-crossing structures. The response variable is binomial (yes=crossed; no = did not cross) and was recorded by animal species. We did about 30 visits to each crossing structure (our random factor) in which we recorded the binomial response by each animal species and the values of a few predictors.

So, I have this (simplified for better understanding) mixed effects model: library (lme4)

Mymodel <- glmer(cross.01 ~ stream.01 + width.m + grass.per + (1|structure.id), 
  data = Mydata, family = binomial)

stream is a factor with 2 levels; width.m is continuous; grass.per is a percentage

This is the model in which I assessed crossings by all species combined (i.e., cross. 01 = 1 when an animal of any species crossed, cross.01 = 0 when no animal crossed). However, we did one model per species and those species-specific models highlight that different species exhibit different relationships between crossings and explanatory variables.

My problem: This means that my model above suffers from an additional source of variation related to the species level without accounting for it. However I cannot recalibrate the above model adding the species level as random factor because, in my binomial response, the zero means no species crossed (all zeros would have "NA" or, say, "none" for species) and so that additional source of variation is only present when the response was 1. Just to confirm this, I did add species as a random factor:

(1 | structure.id) + (1 | species)

As expected, the message is "Error: Response is constant"

How can I account for the species variability in my model in lme4?

Comment: A few more details: I had 5 mammal species crossing through the 30 road-crossing structures. In 134 occasions (i.e., 134 of my records on individual crossing-structures), no animal crossed (a "no cross" was a "zero" for that visit to the crossing-structure). In 498 occasions, at least one animal of a given species crossed the structure (these were my "ones" in my logistic response).

Comment: A side comment: This is to respond to a reviewer in a paper of mine, i.e., I did and presented species-specific and "all combined species" models in the draft reviewed but now the reviewer is asking me to control for the species variability in the "combined species model". He asked me to include a random factor but I realized that is not possible since all my zeros would have "none" for the species that crossed. So, is it possible to account for the species variability in my model in lme4 in another way? I know in nlme including a fitting of variance structures it's not that difficult...